# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum^{\infty}_{k=n} \frac{n}{k^3}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory

> Show that
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=n} \frac{n}{k^3}=0$$

This is a question related to measure theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reformulation:**

Let $\mu$ be the [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) on $\Bbb N$. Then with:
$$f_n(k)=\frac{n}{k^3} \chi_{\{k \geq n\}}$$
you are searching:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{\Bbb N} f_n(k) d\mu(k)$$

**Hint:**

You can notice that:

- For all $k$:
  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(k)=0$$
- With $g(k)=\frac{1}{k^2}$, for all $n$:
  $$\forall k, \, |f_n(k)| \leq g(k)$$
  and $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{\Bbb N} g(k) d\mu(k)<+\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

For $k \geq n$, we have
$$ \frac{n}{k^3} \leq \frac{1}{k^2} \ .$$
It follows that
$$ 0 \leq \sum_{k = n}^\infty \frac{n}{k^3} \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \ .$$
Since
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty \ ,$$
we must have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = 0 \ .$$
The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

We have that (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Approximation_by_definite_integrals))
$$
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^3}\le\int_{n-1}^\infty x^{-3}dx=\frac12\cdot\frac1{(n-1)^2}.
$$